# Upgrading from MongoDB 2.4 to 3.6

Tags: mongodb

I wish to upgrade my mongo from 2.4 to 3.6. As i see in the official documents, and googling, that i need to do an upgrade for each 0.2 version, meaning doing 6 (!!!) upgrades in order to upgrade my db to 3.6.

Is this in any way avoidable? this process is messy as it requires doing so on many servers and on many of our clients.

Furthermore, i cannot seem to make any upgrade work. i have downloaded the 2.6 version and tried to make an upgrade but all the available executable's from mongo's official website have resulted in an unknown exception.

Any advice will be welcomed as im a bit lost in this process.

Comment: What sort of deployments are you upgrading (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster)? Do you have auth enabled? If you aren't using authentication (or want to backup & restore without auth), `mongodump` and `mongorestore` might be a fast track approach. However, you still need to review the [release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/) for successive releases (in particular, Compatibility Changes) as stricter validation may require data changes for successful import. You're catching up on about five years of active development and many features have evolved significantly.

Comment: its standalone, no auth required. does dump/restore include all the databases?

Comment: Yes, `mongodump` will export all data and index definitions, and `mongorestore` will rebuild with indexes. See: [Back Up and Restore with MongDB Tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/#binary-bson-dumps).

Comment: I would also suggest backing up with `mongodump` version 3.6 rather than the original 2.4 `mongodump`. Either version should work, but newer `mongodump` may help with compatibility since your end goal is restoring into MongoDB 3.6.

Comment: @Stennie thanks for everything. Dump/Restore solution is the best choice for me, and your explanations were very helpful. Maybe do a proper answer for this so i can mark it as a solution and vote up?

Answer (score 2):

The best option is (my opinion) mongoexport data to disk and then mongoimport it to 3.6.

Comment: `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` work with data at a collection level and are generally intended for exchanging data with other systems. `mongodump` and `mongorestore` should be used to backup MongoDB deployments if you want to export & import data with type integrity and collection options (such as index definitions).

Comment: I have done import/export and it seems as the indexes are kept.. can you elaborate your last sentence?

Comment: `mongoexport` exports data in plain text (JSON, CSV, or TSV), doesn't export collection options or index definitions, and must be run for each collection. The plain text export doesn't have type fidelity or the metadata required to recreate secondary indexes or collections with special options (for example, capped collections). However, the required  `_id` index will always be created. If you backup with `mongodump` you should notice binary BSON files and `*.metadata.json` text files for each collection. `mongorestore` recreates all collections and indexes with their original options.